# Let enumerate or itemize flow down underneath the point

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I am trying to have multi-line points flow back underneath the number or the point itself like so.
[image]

But the [enumerate](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) doc doesn't help me to achieve the above (the point or number is always floated to the right in its own box).

Can you help me set my items like the above image? So far I have the following:
`\setlist[enumerate]{itemindent=1cm, leftmargin=1cm, labelsep=1cm, labelwidth=1cm}`

Many thanks

Comment: Simply try with `\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, itemindent=1cm}`.

Comment: Thank you your code with slight change worked:
```\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=1cm, wide=0pt}```

Comment: Fine. And welcome to TeX SX! (sorry, I forgot it, in my first comment). Just a small advice: always post a small compilable code that reproduces  your problem, so that people who want to help can see more easily what the problem is.